# localhost not displaying react app: localhost refused to connect

Tags: reactjs, npm, localhost

I tried to npm start an old application after running npm install. it sort of  successfully began to run in terminal, but it mentioned at the end:

```
? Something is already running on port 3000. Probably:
  /usr/local/bin/node /Users/myname/Desktop/Web Dev Projects/React_Testing/react-testing-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js (pid 32733)
  in /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React_Testing/react-testing-app

Would you like to run the app on another port instead? › (Y/n)
```

So, when i run on another port it fails locally, despite it still runnning online.

Terminal errors after running it on another port as suggested:

```
Starting the development server...

/Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/jonathanschimpf/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/web-dev-projects/React-Portfolio/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

Blank page that shows after running npm start reads:

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I honestly am confused. Is there anything that anyone can explain to me on why this isn't showing locally? And how I can possibly can troubleshoot this? I'm confused. thanks in advance!

tried to view an old react app portfolio that is working online on localhost but it did not show.

Comment: "*an old application*" how old? Without any context it seem like a possible issue is a Node version that has breaking changes with some of the old libraries. Try to use something like [**NVM**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide) and try switching to an older Node version.